# Read line as array of bytes without default encoding

Tags: java, java-io

How to read in the most efficient way one line from a file (finished by `\n`, or `\r`, or both) as an array of bytes withouth going through `String` (if I read line into `String`, the default encoding is applied and I don't want to have this step).

Comment: I think the simplicity of the code, when you go through `String` kind of makes it the only game in town for this sort of thing.

Comment: Well, how about reading chunks of bytes and scanning those for the byte values you are looking for (of course you have to interpret the input then in some kind of encoding to see if there is a `\r` or `\n` or both).

Comment: @Chris - But String will apply default encoding and as the file contains parts in different encodings, I don't know how to switch between encoding between lines.

Comment: @Matthias - of course I can read byte by byte until \r or \n (and then skip \r \n or both) but then firsly it's quite "manual" solution, secondly I think it will not be too efficient that's why I decided to ask.

Comment: @user2707175 Well, when I said chunks of bytes, I implied a chunkSize > 1. However, how do you think a BufferedReader does this? Of course there is also a way to guess the encoding if you happen to have files with byte order marks (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) or something like that.

Comment: @Matthias - by encoding I don't mean BOM and Unicode, UTF, but old/Windows solutions where there was no any info in the file about the encoding, moreover it could happen that ex. one line was in one encoding, the second in the second encoding.

Comment: @user2707175 Well, how about you really spend some more time in writing up your question. Give the situation (limitations and an example would be fine), and explain what you have tried and where you are failing and I am sure help will be found. I do not want to waste my time with open ended questions like this where every aproach of a solution is countered with a previously unmentioned limitation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this without doing it manually. But to save you time, I'll write the code for you:

```
public static byte[] firstLine(InputStream in) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; // arbitrary number
    int idx = 0;
    byte b;
    while ((b = in.read()) != 0x0d || b != 0x0a) { // those codes are CR and LF
        if (idx >= buffer.length)
            buffer = Arrays.copyOf(buffer, buffer.length * 2);
        buffer[idx] = b;
    return Arrays.copyOf(buffer, idx);
}
```

Comment: I hoped that perhaps there is some more automatic solution. But thank you for writing code for me ;) and I really like the trick with Arrays.copyOf - simple thing but so powerful! Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @user2707175 I found a bug. Am about to fix it.

Comment: @user2707175 The `Arrays.copyOf` trick is basically what `ArrayList` does behind the scenes, to dynamically change the size of the array it stores data in.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help. In fact still some minor bugs exist but it was very good base for my own program.